# How to enter a new order only if / when the first one has been executed (filled)? [MQL5]

Tags: metatrader4, forex, mql5

I'm kinda of new in MQL5.

I have an EA that buys one stock first (let's say PETR4) and then buys another one (let's say ABEV3).

The  only problem is that I can only order the second one when the first one is executed (not only placed).

I used the **`MqlTradeResult.retcode`** to get the return number, but that only shows if the order has been placed and I need to know if the order has been filled in order to continue with the second operation.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Such indication ought be coded in a `PositionSelect()` call:

First call
**`if ( PositionSelect( "PETR4" ) ) { ... /* further work will go here */}`**

> This chooses an open ***position*** for further working with it. Returns `True` if the function is successfully completed. Returns `False` in case of failure.

If there is any active position reported for the given symbol, the further work will go ahead inside the `{...}`-code-block

The hidden magic is in a fact, there is **either** a **single-*position*** for any symbol, **or none at all**. This makes the rest of the logic crystal-clear.

> Execution of trade operations results in the opening of a ***position***, changing of its volume and/or direction, or its disappearance. Trade operations are conducted based on orders, sent by the `OrderSend()` function in the form of trade requests. For each financial security (symbol) only one open position is possible. A position has a set of properties available for reading by the **`PositionGet...()`** functions.
>   ...
>   **`POSITION_TICKET`**
>   Unique number assigned to each newly opened ***position***. It usually matches the ticket of an order used to open the position except when the ticket is changed as a result of service operations on the server, for example, when charging swaps with position re-opening. To find an order used to open a position, apply the `POSITION_IDENTIFIER` property.
>
> `POSITION_TICKET` value corresponds to `MqlTradeRequest::position`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I tried this function but in my case, I don't need to check if the deal was closed. What I need is something like this: Order 100 PETR4 --- Wait for this order to turn into a deal (gets filled) --- Whe the first order gets filled Order 200 ABEV3. The method that you showed also gets the orders that are filled (deals)

Comment: Seems you missed the point: `... OrderSend( reqStructPETR4, resStructPETR4 ); ... if ( PositionSelect( "PETR4" ) ) /* proves the fill-ed state */ { ... OrderSend( reqStructABEV3, resStructABEV3 ); ... }` is matching your intent. In a not mentioned use-case - If individual positions are allowed ( `ACCOUNT_MARGIN_MODE_RETAIL_HEDGING` ), multiple positions can be open for one symbol. In this case, `PositionSelect()` will select a position with the lowest ticket. This would still lead to a `PositionSelectByTicket()` introspection factory, if in a need to keep the logic of opening an `ABEV3` trade.